# Adjective of "heritage"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to say that my city has a great combination of **_** structures and an ever growing urban life.

What adjective of *heritage* (or other word if suitable) can I use here?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the obvious ***historic***?

Comment: But historic talks nothing about inheritance right?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question I suppose.  What do you mean by inheritance?  Historic conveys that the structures have been there a long time, and all of the implications therein.  If you're talking about something that's even older, "***ancient***" would apply.  Otherwise, please clarify so we can better help you :)

Comment: ok.. I guess `historic` should work well here. But any suggestions about adjective of `heritage`?

Comment: Ever growing urban life has no inherent connection with either *historic* or *heritage*, and neither of those words have much connection with "inheritance" as generally understood.

Comment: My city has a great combination of historic and modern buildings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want a word more like previously-suggested *traditional, vintage,* or *period*, all good, rather than *heritable* or *inheritable*, the adjectival forms probably closest to  *[heritage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heritage)*, which properly is a noun; but note there are numerous uses of the word as an adjective, *e.g.* in *[heritage turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heritage_turkey), heritage species*, and *heritage seeds* [for which *[heirloom seeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heirloom_plant)* is heard more commonly].

Depending on sought effect, some of *distinct, outstanding, stylish, reputed, renowned, registered, nationally-known* or *-listed* may apply.

Comment: NO vintage does not work at all here.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen a large number of instances where *heritage* is used in an adjectival sense, including *heritage structures* itself.

We have a regular *heritage walk* for the interested, as part of *heritage tourism* aimed to create *heritage awareness*, where the walkers visit prominent *heritage structures*.

Let me hasten to add that I am not sure if all of it is grammatically correct.

Comment: Also world heritage sites

Answer (score 2):

I assume historical/historic does not work for you because they are not noted in histories of the region, just older. How about ***older***?

Some more possible synonyms, which may or may not work, depending on what you're trying to say: ***traditional, vintage, conventional, ancestral, period***

Answer (score 1):

Historic does seem to be the best choice in your example, but *hereditary* can also be an adjective form of heritage in other cases.

Comment: Hi Ian and welcome to ELU! This is a good start, but you should consider adding a definition.

Answer (score 0):

To define something as part of a culture or nation's heritage, there are lots of words which cover this, and many seem to be listed here. But to use 'heritage' as the root word of the required adjective is not common. 'Heritable' is the closest I can see, but this puts the focus on future actions in relation to the object in question. A word which focuses instead on the existing state of the object just being part of a heritage would (I imagine) be 'heritageous'.